# MySQL How can I use the result of a stored function as a paramater in the same SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, sql-function

So my question is, how can i use the result of `berekenKosten()` as a parameter for `nogTeBetalen()` in the same SELECT statement? Here is my code:

```
SELECT boeking.Boekingnr, Naam, Telefoonnr, boeking.Aantal_volwassenen, reis.Prijs_per_persoon, boeking.Betaald_bedrag, 
berekenKosten(reis.Prijs_per_persoon, boeking.Aantal_volwassenen) AS totaalprijs, nogTeBetalen()
FROM klant
INNER JOIN boeking ON klant.Klantnr = boeking.Klantnr
INNER JOIN reis ON boeking.Reisnr = reis.Reisnr
```

if this isn't possible, how can I display the result of `nogTeBetalen()` as a column for each row?

i already tried this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT boeking.Boekingnr, Naam, Telefoonnr, boeking.Aantal_volwassenen, reis.Prijs_per_persoon, boeking.Betaald_bedrag, 
berekenKosten(reis.Prijs_per_persoon, boeking.Aantal_volwassenen) AS totaalprijs, nogTeBetalen(totaalprijs)
FROM klant
INNER JOIN boeking ON klant.Klantnr = boeking.Klantnr
INNER JOIN reis ON boeking.Reisnr = reis.Reisnr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the calls:

```
SELECT 
    b.Boekingnr, 
    Naam, 
    Telefoonnr, 
    b.Aantal_volwassenen, 
    r.Prijs_per_persoon, 
    b.Betaald_bedrag, 
    berekenKosten(r.Prijs_per_persoon, b.Aantal_volwassenen) AS totaalprijs, 
    nogTeBetalen(berekenKosten(r.Prijs_per_persoon, b.Aantal_volwassenen)) as result
FROM klant k
INNER JOIN boeking b ON k.Klantnr = b.Klantnr
INNER JOIN reis r ON b.Reisnr = r.Reisnr
```

But it is probably more efficient to use a subquery, so the procedure is only invoked once:

```
SELECT t.*, nogTeBetalen(totaalprijs) as result
FROM (
    SELECT 
        b.Boekingnr, 
        Naam, 
        Telefoonnr, 
        b.Aantal_volwassenen, 
        r.Prijs_per_persoon, 
        b.Betaald_bedrag, 
        berekenKosten(r.Prijs_per_persoon, b.Aantal_volwassenen) AS totaalprijs
    FROM klant k
    INNER JOIN boeking b ON k.Klantnr = b.Klantnr
    INNER JOIN reis ON b.Reisnr = r.Reisnr
) t
```

Side recommendations:

- use table aliases to shorten the query and increase its readability, as shown above
- do prefix each and every columnm with the (alias of) the table it belongs to, so the query is umabiguous about the underlying data structures; there a a few unqualified columns in the `SELECT` clause that you would need to fix